# RichFaces' autocomplete is not showing suggestions

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I'm trying to get a popup with suggestions using the following code:

```
<rich:autocomplete value="#{solrManager.queryString}" autocompleteMethod="#{solrManager.getSuggestions}" mode="ajax"/>

public class SolrManager implements Serializable {
  ...
  public List<String> getSuggestions(Object request){
    List<String> suggestions = new ArrayList<String>();
    suggestions.add("test 1");
    suggestions.add("test 2");
    suggestions.add("test 3");
    suggestions.add("test 4");
    return suggestions;
  }
  ...
}
```

I tried both `String` and `Object` parameters of method `getSuggestions` and didn't succeed.

I use 4.3.3.Final version of RichFaces and 2.2.3 version of JSF.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. The method signature for the `autocompleteMethod` has changed. Try

```
public List<String> getSuggestions(FacesContext ctx, UIComponent c, String prefix) {
  // ... snip ...
  return suggestions;
}
```